# How can I chose elements inside of a string with Python?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, split

I have a list of strings where each string contain information that I would like to be able to select independently. The format of the strings makes also difficult the split() option.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Location': {0: 'Madrid', 1: 'Barcelona', 2: 'Paris', 3: 'London', 4: 'New_York', 5: 'Berlin', 6:'Birminham', 7:'Tanzania'},
                   'Positions': {0: 'Auditor or Auditor(S), Accountant or Accountant(S), PayRoll_Manager, 2 Brand_Manager, 3 IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security', 1: 'Accountant or Accountant(S), PayRoll_Manager, Brand_Manager, 2 Developer, Cyber_security', 2:'Auditor or Auditor(S), 2 Accountant, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security', 3: 'Auditor or Auditor(S), Accountant, PayRoll_Manager, 3 Brand_Manager, 2 IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security', 4: 'Auditor or Auditor(S), Accountant or Accountant(S), PayRoll_Manager, Brand_Manager, IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security', 5: 'Auditor or Auditor(S), 2 PayRoll_Manager, Brand_Manager, 2 Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security',6: 'Auditor or Auditor(S), IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security', 7: 'Auditor or Auditor(S), Accountant, PayRoll_Manager, Brand_Manager'}})
```

In the column "Positions", inside of each string there are many roles separated by commas, and also there are elements that contain the word "or". I wonder if there is any way to organise this so I can select independently elements inside of one string (for example: only "PayRoll_Manager"). I also wonder if somehow I can write a code where the program understand that if there is an Auditor(S), then I do not need and Auditor, or vice versa, but no both at the same time. And another issue would be the numbers in front of some of the positions which indicate how many of them it is needed. Can I write a code that will select how many I actually need.

The point of this is that I have another data with employees with different skills and i need to match them with what is required in new locations from another dataframe.

Comment: Does the number of role small? If so, try get all unique position first. Then it can be represent in sparse matrix. The existence and number can be extract using regex, but I am not sure about the "S". If the "S", and non-S always came together then you can treat it as one. Else after extract, you might want to set non-S column to `0` if S column is `> 0` (using `np.where`)

Comment: I believe you are looking for "stemming" and or "lemmatizing". A good NL module should support this kind of tokenization for you. I would start with `ntlk` or `spaCy`

Answer (score 0):

One method for dealing with this type of information is to take the data from the strings and transform it into an organised format, such as a list of dictionaries. A method to try is as follows:

```py
def extract_data(row):
    positions = row['Positions'].split(',')
    result = []
    for pos in positions:
        if 'or' in pos:
            pos = pos.split(' or ')[0].strip()
        if '(' in pos:
            pos = pos.split('(')[0].strip()
        if pos[-1].isdigit():
            pos_count = int(pos[-1])
            pos = pos[:-2].strip()
        else:
            pos_count = 1
        result.append({'Position': pos, 'Count': pos_count})
    return result

df1['Positions'] = df1.apply(extract_data, axis=1)
```

This code applies the extract data function to each row of the dataframe using the data frame's apply method. The function divides the string on commas to get a list of distinct places. The location name, count, and any additional information in parenthesis are then extracted from each position individually using a variety of string operations. A list of dictionaries containing the processed positions is then returned.

When this code is executed, a list of dictionaries will replace the Positions column in df1; each dictionary will include details about a single position. Then, you may retrieve this data in a more organised way, for instance, to receive a list of all the openings in Madrid:

```py
madrid_positions = df1[df1['Location'] == 'Madrid']['Positions'].iloc[0]
```

This code retrieves the first (and only) element in the Positions column to obtain the list of positions for Madrid after using boolean indexing to pick just the rows where the location is "Madrid."

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help.What is the "count" for? I get number 1 for all the positions[{'Position': 'Auditor', 'Count': 1},{'Position': ' Accountant', 'Count': 1}... ]On the other hand,how would I match another df2 with these results? Lets say that I have another df2 with employees ID and the skills they have  (for example employee ID 1234 is Accountant and PayRoll_Manager) Therefore, if I need to cover a position of Accountant in Madrid, could I match the employee with ID 1234 from df2 to this position in Madrid considering that the results of your scripts contain "position" and "count"? Thank